# PHP results from sql array not printing to screen

Tags: php

I have a database that I'm querying and having the results echo out onto the screen. The lines echo out right up to the point of getting the info from the array returned from the database. I cant seem to find out why the data is omitted.

```
case 'search':
echo "<br>";
echo "searching: ".$firstname;
echo "<br>";



$sqlsearch="SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE firstname='$firstname'";


$data = mysql_query($conndb, $sqlsearch);

//$row = mysql_fetch_array($results);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data));
{
echo "firstname: ".$row['firstname']."<br>";
echo "lastname: ".$row['lastname']."<br>";  
echo "phone: ".$row['phone']."<br>";
echo "address: ".$row['address']."<br>";
echo "city: ".$row['city']."<br>";
echo "state: ".$row['state']."<br>";
echo "zip: ".$row['zip']."<br>";
echo $sqlsearch;
break;
}

echo "<br>";
echo "seaching 2";
mysql_close($condb);
break;
```

The output if I run this, searching for a user with the first name "Jon" that I have entered in the database, so I know the connection is working, at least for input looks like this:

```
searching: Jon
firstname: 
lastname: 
phone: 
address: 
city: 
state: 
zip: 
SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE firstname='Jon'
```

Customer is a table with the following fields firstname, lastname, phone, address, city, state, zip. Those are the exact names and cases of the columns. I do not have any one field listed as a primary key as i did not set it up that way.

Comment: What do you get when you run that query in phpmyadmin? Are you sure there are results and that row has values for those fields?... well, it should at least put out Jon

Comment: I dont know what phpmyadmin is.

Comment: Run the query directly on your MySQL server and see if you are getting results for it

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are **no longer maintained** and shouldn't be used in any new codebase. It is being phased out in favor of newer APIs. Instead you should use [**prepared statements**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).

Comment: I do, the query works fine when running there.

Comment: From the PHP manual: Note: Field names returned by this function [mysql_fetch_array] are case-sensitive.  Do a print_r of the array to see what is in it, and specifically what the keys are.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the `Customer` table definition?

Comment: I usually run only the query with the function, something this way mysql_query( $query ); Connect to your sql serve via a separate file.. like this  $con = mysql_connect( $hst, $usr, $pwd ); mysql_select_db( $bd ); Sure will work for you. But if the problem is not with your connection .. than post your SQL here for us!

Answer (score 0):

Not that I should be promoting mysql_ functions since they're deprecated, but have you tried switching the parameters?

```
mysql_query($conndb, $sqlsearch);
```

should be

```
mysql_query($sqlsearch, $conndb);
```

according to these docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Please note the enormous warning at the top of that page and how it suggests using mysqli or PDO

Comment: It makes no difference oddly, doesnt cause it to fail worse or work better.